# How do you convert a Date in the form of a String to a ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am trying to create a stream that includes Twitter data + my app's but I'm having trouble sorting them because their time stamps are formatted in different ways. This is my code:

```
answers = Answer.find(:all, :conditions => {:user_id => @user_id }, :limit => 20)
tweets = Twitter::Search.new(params[:username]).to_a

@feed = (answers + tweets).sort_by(&:created_at)

these are the formats on time:

<#Hashie::Mash created_at="Tue, 22 Jun 2010 04:41:23 +0000"...
<Answer id:... created_at: "2010-06-15 02:13:40"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats the problem you are having? are they not sorting properly because of the string format for each type of class is different? Or is your issue that you can't get them to print out in the same format?

Comment: they aren't printing out in the same format and thus can't be sorted together through :created_at

@feed = (answers + tweets).sort_by(&:created_at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but try this:

```
@feed = (answers + tweets).sort_by{ |x| DateTime.parse("#{x.created_at}") }
```

**Edit**

Reverse:

```
@feed = (answers + tweets).sort{ |x, y| DateTime.parse("#{y.created_at}") <=> DateTime.parse("#{x.created_at}") }
```

Comment: awesome. that works I just need to throw the sorting in reverse. do you know how to do that?